# Forecasting multivariate time series data stream

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, online-algorithms

I have a multivariate time series data stream. I am looking for a method that can forecast the next value of one of the variables *as the data comes in*. (It would be a major advantage if there's an R package that does it.)

Currently I am using a VAR to do this. Say I have 1000 records. I estimate the VAR for those 1000 rows, and do my forecast. Then when the 1001st row comes in, I estimate a brand new VAR *from scratch*, based on the 1001 rows that I now have. I assume there's a more efficient method, some sort of model that can be updated as each new record is available.

I don't know much statistics, so if you can keep the explanation simple, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try for PSF (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304131481_PSF_Introduction_to_R_Package_for_Pattern_Sequence_Based_Forecasting_Algorithm).
The R package is available CRAN named as PSF.